# Killing the Finder, Spotlight "Dead" in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cpu, finder

For music making, I am writing a bash script (well, list of [pkills](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20030620102036392) or [my own updated version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946462/little-bash-script-catch-errors/1946586#1946586)) in OS X to remove unnecessary CPU-using programs. Even if I am forced to reboot afterwards, I do not mind. I need CPU use (and memory use, perhaps more importantly) at a bare minimum.

I have tried `killall Finder` which seems to just restart the finder. I know that Path Finder actually kills the Finder so that it doesn't restart, but I don't know how they do that. My questions are:

1. **How can I kill the Finder and Spotlight so that they do not restart?**
2. Once this works, to reboot I can always hardboot. If not, **what is my lowest CPU-usage way to initiate a reboot process correctly?** Leave a Terminal window open?

**Note:** Although this is kind of implicit in the question: I do NOT want any changes to be persistent after rebooting.

**Update:** I might use `sudo mdutil -i off /` to shut off Spotlight indexing. Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your performance gain by doing either of these is so miniscule as to not be worth it. If you have a pre-10.6 machine you can save a bit of RAM by not having too many items on your desktop.

If you insist you can add a quit option to the Finder with:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder QuitMenuItem -bool YES
```

You have to restart for the Quit to show up, and you won't see what's on the desktop once you Quit the Finder.

Your command for spotlight is correct for the boot, but you can also specify other drives in place of /. You may find that [Spotless](http://www.fixamac.net/software/spot3/index.php) shuts down more processes, and it is great if you are plugging in many drives and don't want them to automatically be indexed.

Comment: All good stuff, and true about performance gain, but I'm quitting many many annoying processes like ituneshelper and evernote helper and anything that doesn't bring my system to its knees. So every little bit counts.

Comment: You might benefit by creating a new user to do your audio work that doesn't have Evernote and other 3rd party applications installed. It would be easier than quitting all sorts of processes, and you could use /Users/Shared to pick up files from your regular account.

Comment: That would be cool. I'll see what kind of serial number problems I have in doing that...

Comment: If your applications are installed to /Applications instead of your User folder you should have no problems at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using `mdutil` to turn off Spotlight indexing will turn off Spotlight indexing for that drive across boots. If you have multiple drives however it will still index other drives as the last argument is meant to specify what drive.

You can safely quit the Finder from the GUI by adding a Quit menu item to the Finder menu using the command: `defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem -bool YES`. Also using `kill` instead of `killall` tends not to restart the Finder.

Comment: so you means that I will need to mdutil ... on, even if I reboot?

Comment: kill tends to have the Finder restart. Not sure who is doing it, though.

Comment: in 10.6 (not sure before) the QuitMenuItem 1 doesn't work. Must be -bool YES like in ridogi's answer.

Comment: I believe QuitMenuItem 1 will work in 10.4 and possibly older versions, but I don't know how far back.

Comment: @ridogi - Thanks. I've corrected that.

Comment: @Yar: mdutil only needs to be run once to disable it permanently. You need to turn it back on if you want to enable Spotlight indexing of that drive again later.